# MYSQL Check if for all table 1 entries has table 2 entry against it

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables Employees and Certificates. Now I have 4 certificates and I want to check for every employee which certificates are passed and which are not.

```
Select Distinct(certificate.certificatename)
FROM `employeemanagement$certificate` certificate
Where certificatename = '**********' 
or certificatename = '************'
or certificatename = '************'
or certificatename = '************'
```

this will give me the 4 certificate i want

```
SELECT employees.employeeid, employees.employeename, certificate.certificatename, certificate.expirationdate, certificate.`status`
FROM `employeemanagement$employees` employees 
LEFT JOIN `employeemanagement$certificate_employees` certifcate_employees on employees.id = certifcate_employees.`employeemanagement$employeesid`
LEFT JOIN `employeemanagement$certificate` certificate on certificate.id = certifcate_employees.`employeemanagement$certificateid`
Where employees.currentstatus = 'Active'
```

and this gives me all the employees with all the certificate they have passed but it wont give me result for every certificate

Comment: What happen when you remove `Where employees.currentstatus = 'Active'` and run the query?

Comment: Then it will show all the employees. It doesn't matter because I only need the record for active employees

Answer (score 0):

I think conditional aggregation is a reasonable approach:

```
SELECT e.employeeid, e.employeename, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN c.certificatename = 'C1' THEN  c.expirationdate END) as c1_expiration,
       MAX(CASE WHEN c.certificatename = 'C1' THEN  c.staus END) as c1_status, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN c.certificatename = 'C2' THEN  c.expirationdate END) as c2_expiration,
       MAX(CASE WHEN c.certificatename = 'C2' THEN  c.staus END) as c2_status, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN c.certificatename = 'C3' THEN  c.expirationdate END) as c3_expiration,
       MAX(CASE WHEN c.certificatename = 'C3' THEN  c.staus END) as c3_status, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN c.certificatename = 'C4' THEN  c.expirationdate END) as c4_expiration,
       MAX(CASE WHEN c.certificatename = 'C4' THEN  c.staus END) as c4_status
FROM `employeemanagement$employees` e LEFT JOIN 
     `employeemanagement$certificate_employees` ce
      ON e.id = ce.`employeemanagement$employeesid` LEFT JOIN
     `employeemanagement$certificate` c
     ON c.id = ce.`employeemanagement$certificateid`
WHERE e.currentstatus = 'Active'
GROUP BY e.employeeid;
```

You might find it easier to work with one row per employee with all the certificates summarized on that row, rather than multiple rows per certificate.